# problem with focusrite scarlett 2i2 ubuntu 19.10

Tags: 19.10

i recently installed ubuntu 19.10 and i have a problem with my audio interface focusrite scarlett 2i2. the problem is that when switching  audio sources (for example a video player and the  browser, or even going from youtube to vimeo or when receiving a  notification from a website) the interface disconnects and  reconnects. is there a way to avoid it? other than that it works perfectly. thanks